# Include multiple bar charts with callback interaction - dash

Tags: plotly, dependencies, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm aiming to plot multiple graphs in a dbc.Container that can be manipulated with various filtering controls. The following app layout includes a `DatePickerRange` for dates, `Dropdown` for days of the week, and a `Checklist` for unique values.

I aiming to plot two distinct bar charts that use `DATE` and `Type` columns. I'm also attempting to link both figures to **ALL** filtering options so any alteration will influence both bar charts at the same time.

I've attempted to achieve this using separate callbacks but only `DATE` bar chart is plotted. The filtering options currently has no interactivity.

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
           'Type': ['A','B','B','C','D','D','E','E','F'],
           })

N = 30
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))

df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()

df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.floor('1min')

df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])

df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])

df['YEAR'] = df['DATE'].dt.year

df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')

df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday

df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)

df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[
    ################### Filter box ###################### 
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Filter by date (D-M-Y):'),
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='input_date',
            month_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
            show_outside_days=True,
            minimum_nights=0,
            initial_visible_month=dt(2022, 1, 1),
            min_date_allowed=dt(2016, 1, 1),
            max_date_allowed=dt(2022, 12, 31),
            start_date=dt.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
            end_date=dt.strptime("2022-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        ),

        html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='DOW',
            options=[
                {'label': 'Sun', 'value': '1'},
                {'label': 'Mon', 'value': '2'},
                {'label': 'Tue', 'value': '3'},
                {'label': 'Wed', 'value': '4'},
                {'label': 'Thurs', 'value': '5'},
                {'label': 'Fri', 'value': '6'},
                {'label': 'Sat', 'value': '7'}
            ],
            value=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'],
            multi=True
        ),

        html.Label('Type:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id='Type',
            options=[
                {'label': 'A', 'value': '1'},
                {'label': 'B', 'value': '2'},
                {'label': 'C', 'value': '3'},
                {'label': 'D', 'value': '4'},
                {'label': 'E', 'value': '5'},
                {'label': 'F', 'value': '6'},
            ],
            value=['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'],
        ),

    ], className="four columns",
    style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

])

success_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Type Count"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_types', style={"color": "Purple"})
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

failure_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Date Count"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_dates', style={"color": "Black"})
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(success_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert pie chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = "type-bar-chart")),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(failure_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert bar chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph()),
            ], className="h-100"),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)

@app.callback(
    Output('type-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("Type", "value")
    ])

@app.callback(
    Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input("DOW", "value")
    ])    

def date_chart(value):

    #bar_data = df[df['DOW'] == value]

    count = df['DOW'].value_counts()

    data = go.Bar(x = count.index, y = count.values)

    layout = go.Layout(title = 'DOW')

    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)  

    return fig    

def type_chart(value):

    #bar_data = df[df['Type'] == value]

    count = df['Type'].value_counts()

    data = go.Bar(x = count.index, y = count.values)

    layout = go.Layout(title = 'Type')

    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)  

    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port = 8051)
```

Intended output:

1. Type bar chart should be displayed as the bottom left figure (not `DOW`).
2. Filter box containing `DatePickerRange` for dates, `Dropdown` for days of the week, and a `Checklist` for unique values in `Type` should interact simultaneously with both figures (`DOW`,`Type`)

[image]

Comment: You are defining Id of Dropdown is `DOW` but you set Input is `DATE`. So I thịn it's the problem.

Comment: Thanks I fixed that part but now they're the same output for both figures and there is still no interactivity from the filter functions.

Comment: Can you add your expect Ouput image?

Comment: Included now @hoatran

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw that you did not filter your dataframe with filters and then use it to return graphs so that it did not work. I think you should revise your code as below to make it work.

```
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from datetime import datetime
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

df = pd.DataFrame({
           'Type': ['A','B','B','C','D','D','E','E','F'],
           })

N = 30
df = pd.concat([df] * N, ignore_index=True)
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.date_range(start='2022/01/01 07:30', end='2022/01/30 08:30', periods=len(df))
df['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'], dayfirst = True).sort_values()
df['TIMESTAMP'] = df['TIMESTAMP'].dt.floor('1min')
df['DATE'], df['TIME'] = zip(*[(d.date(), d.time()) for d in df['TIMESTAMP']])
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['YEAR'] = df['DATE'].dt.year
df = df.sort_values(by = 'DATE')
df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.weekday
df = df.sort_values('DOW').reset_index(drop=True)
df['DOW'] = df['DATE'].dt.day_name()


external_stylesheets = [dbc.themes.SPACELAB, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP]

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets = external_stylesheets)

filter_box = html.Div(children=[
    ################### Filter box ###################### 
    html.Div(children=[
        html.Label('Filter by date (D-M-Y):'),
        dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id='input_date',
            month_format='DD/MM/YYYY',
            show_outside_days=True,
            minimum_nights=0,
            initial_visible_month=dt(2022, 1, 1),
            min_date_allowed=dt(2016, 1, 1),
            max_date_allowed=dt(2022, 12, 31),
            start_date=dt.strptime("2022-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d").date(),
            end_date=dt.strptime("2022-12-31", "%Y-%m-%d").date()
        ),

        html.Label('Day of the week:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem'}),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='DOW',
            options=[
                {'label': x, 'value': x} for x in df['DOW'].unique()
            ],
            value=['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday'],
            multi=True
        ),

        html.Label('Type:', style={'paddingTop': '2rem', 'display': 'inline-block'}),
        dcc.Checklist(
            id='Type',
            options=[
                {'label': 'A', 'value': 'A'},
                {'label': 'B', 'value': 'B'},
                {'label': 'C', 'value': 'C'},
                {'label': 'D', 'value': 'D'},
                {'label': 'E', 'value': 'E'},
                {'label': 'F', 'value': 'F'},
            ],
            value=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
        ),

    ], className="four columns",
    style={'padding':'2rem', 'margin':'1rem'} )

])

success_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Type Count"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_types', style={"color": "Purple"})
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

failure_card = dbc.Card(
    [
        dbc.CardHeader("Some header"),
        dbc.CardBody(
            [
                html.H6("Date Count"),
                html.Div(id='count_of_dates', style={"color": "Black"})
            ]
        ),
    ],
    className='text-center m-4'
)

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.Div(filter_box, className="bg-secondary h-100"), width=2),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(success_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = 'date-bar-chart'), style={
                        "padding-bottom": "10px",
                    },),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert pie chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id = "type-bar-chart")),
            ]),
        ], width=5),
        dbc.Col([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col(failure_card),
            ]),
            dbc.Row([
                # insert bar chart
                dbc.Col(dcc.Graph()),
            ], className="h-100"),
        ], width=5),
    ])
], fluid=True)

@app.callback(
    Output('date-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('input_date','start_date'), 
     Input('input_date','end_date'),
     Input("DOW", "value"),
     Input("Type", "value")])    

def date_chart(start_date, end_date, dow, types):
    dff= df[(df['DATE'] >= start_date)&(df['DATE'] <= end_date)]
    dff = dff[dff['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    dff = dff[dff['Type'].isin(types)]
    count = dff['DOW'].value_counts()
    data = go.Bar(x = count.index, y = count.values)
    layout = go.Layout(title = 'DOW')
    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)  

    return fig    

@app.callback(
    Output('type-bar-chart', 'figure'),
    [Input('input_date','start_date'), 
     Input('input_date','end_date'),
     Input("DOW", "value"),
     Input("Type", "value")])    

def date_chart(start_date, end_date, dow, types):
    dff= df[(df['DATE'] >= start_date)&(df['DATE'] <= end_date)]
    dff = dff[dff['DOW'].isin(dow)]
    dff = dff[dff['Type'].isin(types)]
    count = dff['Type'].value_counts()
    data = go.Bar(x = count.index, y = count.values)
    layout = go.Layout(title = 'Type')
    fig = go.Figure(data = data, layout = layout)  

    return fig 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, port = 8051)
```

[image]